# What is the use of WM_SYSCHAR?

Tags: windows, winapi

[TranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), in response to `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` messages, generates [WM_SYSCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages in a way that is parallel to its processing of `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_CHAR`. But what is the use of these messages? They cannot be interpreted as the user typing text, and they can also not be interpreted as hotkeys (because that's what `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` is for). So, what use are they? Does the (always mysterious) `DefWindowProc` do anything with these messages? What could/should I use them for in my applications (or should they be ignored)?

MSDN's [Keyboard Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page, under the heading *Character Messages*, says the following:

> The WM_SYSCHAR message indicates a system character. As with WM_SYSKEYDOWN, you should generally pass this message directly to DefWindowProc. Otherwise, you may interfere with standard system commands. In particular, do not treat WM_SYSCHAR as text that the user has typed.

Which says all that it is not, but fails to specify what could break if `DefWindowProc` does not get to see these messages? Not to mention that `TranslateMessage` is not a requirement for a functioning message loop, so `DefWindowProc` could, I think, not count on these messages being generated.

Comment: You are overlooking localization, accelerators that need to match menu item text.  Alt+D is for example useless on a Russian machine, their alphabet doesn't have a D.  You really like to specify Alt+д in the accelerator table.  A completely different key.

Comment: @HansPassant: That is a good point, however the documentation of `TranslateAccelerator` states that it uses `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, and not `WM_CHAR` messages. Also, I can only assume that Alt+д should still produce a `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message with some virtual keycode corresponding roughly to the same place on the US keyboard as the original key on the Russian keyboard. Maybe I'm missing something, or the MSDN documentation could be sloppy.